# Move logic higher up in the widget tree

Tags: flutter, refactoring

Is it better to write this:

```
 Column(children: [
                    if (_isSignUp) TextFieldView(
                      key: firstNameKey,
                      label: "First Name",
                    ) else SizedBox.shrink(),
                    if (_isSignUp) TextFieldView(
                      key: lastNameKey,
                      label: "Last name",
                    ) else SizedBox.shrink(),
                  ],),
```

Or this:

```
_isSignUp ? Column(children: [
                        TextFieldView(
                          key: firstNameKey,
                          label: "First Name",
                        ),
                        TextFieldView(
                          key: lastNameKey,
                          label: "Last name",
                        ),
                      ],) : SizedBox.shrink()
```

Is it related to the open-closed principle? I am sure the second example is a much better way of doing things but why? When do we create a new widget and when is it better to just introduce a new if statement?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an specific technical term for this as they are just conditionals.
As for performance the second approach is a `little` better as a SizedBox is cheaper(to layout) than a column, but flutter is really good at drawing widgets. But if you don't wan't to waste any CPU cycle you could use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/nil) package.

I would strive for maintainability here and would choose example 2.
As it is easier to keep adding and deleting items from the column.

Other approach that you could do is to extract the widget creation to a method in case you have more complicated conditions.

```dart
Column(children: [
...myComplicatedMethod()
                  ],),

List<Widget> myComplicatedMethod(){
return [                    if (_isSignUp) TextFieldView(
                      key: firstNameKey,
                      label: "First Name",
                    ) else SizedBox.shrink(),
                    if (_isSignUp) TextFieldView(
                      key: lastNameKey,
                      label: "Last name",
                    ) else SizedBox.shrink(),]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both makes no difference but we prefer ternary coz we need to press less keys to implement it. Also its easily readable so go with B :p